# droid explorer device not found

Tags: droid-explorer

I have an Xperia Z C6606 rooted

Android version 4.3

I have tried both 4.3 and 7 Android SDK.

I kept getting the error message "device '' not found" as shown in the below screenshot.

[image: device not found]

Comment: Have you enabled the ADB USB Debugging mode on the device?

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the platform tools API 23 file size 9 MB and remove the previous one. And remaining the same.

Your device will be visible.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem.
The solution is to grant root access to ADB in *Developer options*.
First of all you need to enable *Developer options* as explained on [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options.html) then you enter *Developer options* as explained there as well.
If you run CyanogenMod/LineageOS you can easily allow root access for ADB as explained [here](https://www.androidexplained.com/cyanogenmod-enable-root/).
Otherwise you have to do it via [Terminal](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69108/how-to-start-root-shell-with-android-studio).

Answer (score -2):

Also ensure you are connected to your PC as Mass Storage (UMS).

Comment: Mass storage is long obsoleted (starting with Android 4.0), so most devices won't even support it anymore. Apart from which, how should that be relevant? From the screenshot it rather looks like OP might have not installed the device-specific drivers.